# Can I add a self-signed certificate to my WebEngine in JavaFX to connect to a https Web server?

Tags: php, ssl, https, javafx-2

I have a JavaFX-2.2 application, that uses a webengine to load some php and html pages from a web server. My application and the web server are not in the same machine. My login php page uses a self-signed certificate. In my client side where the webengine is, i want to connect to that php using the client certificate which is signed by the same CA, as the server's certificate. I want with that way, only my application to have access to the servers pages.
I have read the webengine [api](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) but i have not found yet a way to do so. Also a google search returns a few lemmas .

Can i do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to add one but every time a visitor visits your site, it will show the "This site's security can not be trusted" page.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to use SSL authorization.
1. Your server signed as server.
2. Your application signed as client.

Only both sign can connect. No other servers, no other clients.

In that case you must integrate server public key in client. And client public key in server. (different API and methods use for it) almost all language and servers work fine with SSL authorization.

You can use Self signed keys, or you may generate free pair here: www.startssl.com